# WPF trigger set children elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Action}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource MenuImageStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Styles:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="MenuTextStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#206c8e" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="MenuImageStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/menuButtonHover.png" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

but I need swap both together on mouse over on Grid or Button, but I can not figure out how.

I need something like this. This is only explanation, not valid

```
    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="MenuGridStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetType="Image" Property="Source" Value="Assets/menuButtonHover.png" />
                <Setter TargetType="TextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#206c8e" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: It's not very clear. What do you need to swap? The image with the text block? The foreground with the background? One style with the other?

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski I edit question, I hope you understand me now

Comment: @Peter give a name to your TextBlock and Image and then use the TargetName's Property of Setter.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski
<Image x:Name="ButtonImage"  Style="{StaticResource MenuImageStyle}" />

<Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="Assets/menuButtonHover.png" />

I get error: The name "ButtonImage" is not recognized.

Comment: I try x:Name="ButtonImage" and Name="ButtonImage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is best practice, but should be work.

Add Names like @PiotrWolkowski says

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="ButtonImage" Style="{StaticResource MenuImageStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Name="ButtonText" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

and modify your styles triggers like this

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButtonText, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/menuButtonHover.png" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/menuButtonHover.png" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>

<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButtonImage, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#206c8e" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#206c8e" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```